# How to compare row to previous row in CSV?

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

How do I compare a row to the previous row in a CSV file?

I need it for my if condition:

```
if row[0] != row[0][of previous row]:
    do something....
```

Comment: In your loop create `previous = row` at the end of the loop.

Comment: What should happen for the first row of the file which doesn't have a previous row?

Comment: Is `row[0]` an entire row from the file or is it the first item of the current row? Please show your entire file reading/processing loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program do what you want:

```
import csv

f = open("some.csv", "r+")
ff = csv.reader(f)

pre_line = ff.next()
while(True):
    try:
        cur_line = ff.next()
        if pre_line == cur_line:
            pass #replace pass with do_something()
        pre_line = cur_line
    except:
        break
```

As you see above, I looped over the lines in the csv file, and checked each line with the previous using and iterator. If they are equal I called `do_something()` method, and if they weren't equal it just went to next line.

Comment: what do ff.next()? thanks for tip i building in my mind how can i rebuild my script :)

Comment: @MTG `ff` acts like a list of lines in csv. `ff.next()` return a line each time you call it untill you receive the last line. In python we call ff an iterating variable and next() is iterator. Google "iterator is python".

Comment: @MTG What do you mean by don't work? Did you received any error?

Comment: @MTG Which kind of error do you receive? (So you may want to mark it as answer?)

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a great tool for working with csv's. In this case if you are comparing integers you can use `diff()`. When the rows are equal `diff()` will equal 0. This can be applied to the entire dataframe as in `df.diff()` or to a particular series (a column) as `df.column_name.diff()` or `df['column_name'].diff()`. You can even take the difference between columns or change the period to calculate the difference over, check out the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Comment: Thanks for info i must check it :)